# What type of partition will be created by Boot Camp Assistant?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, filesystem

Will Boot Camp Assistant create an "OS X Extended" partition for Windows as well? Or can I choose the type of file system format?

Comment: Boot Camp Assistant creates a FAT32 partition named BOOTCAMP and then **must** be formatted by Windows Setup to NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

Boot Camp Assistant creates a **FAT32 formatted partition**, not a blank partition. The OS installer you use will reformat the partition, most likely to NTFS if you are using a recent Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

It will create a blank partition which will then get formatted NTFS by your Windows installer.

From Apple's Support Article:  [How to install Windows using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468), Step #4 is:

> #### Format your Windows partition
>
> When you complete the assistant, your Mac restarts to the Windows
> installer. When you're asked where you want to install Windows, select
> the BOOTCAMP partition, then click [Format](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204009).

Comment: This is incorrect. The partition is not 'blank'/free space.